# Move a WordPress Site to Openshift

Tags: mysql, wordpress, migration, openshift

I have a working WordPress website hosted at Hostgator which I want to move to Openshift. Till now I have done :

- Downloaded the entire WP installation(including wp-includes, wp-admin,wp-content etc.)
- Downloaded the original MySql database with phpmyadmin(both zipped and .sql format)
- Installed fresh WP on Openshift, later I logged in into the database of this new installation and dropped all the tables(with phpmyadmin).
- Thereafter uploaded the original database, successfully imported into the new Openshift database(with phpmyadmin).
- Then I upload all original downloaded WordPress installation files into the Openshift one, overwriting everything.

Now I see a database connection error. I guess Openshift doesn't recognize wp-config.php details which consists of the Hostgator data(which I am confused as I don't know if I should be editing the one in the GIT folder or the one in the app-root/current).
Request a step-by-step process. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the [Openshift Wordpress quickstart](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application_types), and get a Wordpress application deployed and then just restore the DB.

Comment: what about themes, plugins and custom changes, i guess with import those things do not come